# Where is customer_entity_static table in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, data-migration, data-migration-tool

while data:migration i get error

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table customer_entity_static
```

But there is no table with this name. Does anyone had similar problem with this table?

Source: magento 1.9.3.4
Destination: magento 2.4.1

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found solution for this problem. The real problem is with custom customer attribute. Magento refers to table using `attribute type`. Check `/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Customer/Model/AttributesDataToCustomerEntityRecords.php`. There is method called **updateCustomerEntities** which call **fetchAttributesData**. Last parameter is array with attributes `backend_type`. I have in this table `static` `backend_type` (for now, i don't know why i have this in array).
To find out which attribute cause the problem you can debug **updateCustomerEntities** method. Just put

```
var_dump($attributeCodesById);
var_dump($attributeIdsByType);
die;
```

after `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
 $eavAttributes = $this->entityTypeCode->getAttributesData($entityTypeCode);
 if (is_array($eavAttributes) && isset($eavAttributes[$attributeCode])) {
    $attributeId = $eavAttributes[$attributeCode]['attribute_id'];
    $attributeBackendType = $eavAttributes[$attributeCode]['backend_type'];
    $attributeIdsByType[$attributeBackendType][] = $attributeId;
    $attributeCodesById[$attributeId] = $attributeCode;
    }
}
```

and run `migrate:data`.
In first array you will get table with attributes where key is attribute id, and value is attribute code.
In second array you will have attributes types (as key) and attributes ids (as value).
In my case in static i have one attribute. This attribute gives problem.

Answer (score 0):

That table is not a built in Magento table, it was installed via extension or by your own custom code. You can figure out what module installed it in your Magento 1 installation by searching your project's config.xml files for the one that defines the `customer_entity_static` table. In order to get past the error you have two options:

1. Install the Magento 2 version of that extension in your 2.4.1 installation, which will create the table for you so you can migrate data to it
2. Update your data-migration-tool to ignore that table so nothing tries to migrate to it

Comment: Thanks for response. 
I searched magento 1 code and didn't find ```customer_entity_static```. I also add this table to <ignore> but this didn't help. Problem is that magento do the select query on this table. And please note, that this table did not exist in M1 db

Comment: So just to clarify, the `customer_entity_static` table doesn't exist in your M1 db and is not defined in your M1 `app/code/local` or `app/code/community` directories? As for the `<ignore>` did you put it in your `map.xml` (`map.xml.dist`) file under `<document_rules>`?

Comment: You are correct. There is no table in db, there is no ```customer_entity_static``` in ```code``` folder and i also added this table in ```map.xml```. This is super strange.

Comment: Super strange indeed...Is it possible `customer_entity_static` got defined in one of your mapping files somehow?

Comment: I searched for ```customer_entity_static``` in my M2 code and also in M1 code. I found nothing. Have no idea where the problem is. I will dig into it, and if i find something i will post answer here.